# What does this bash script actually do?

Tags: bash, shell, solr, wget

```
#!/bin/bash

# Setup Variables
hostName=localhost
portNum=8080
SOLRPATH=/solr
SOLR='delta-import&clean=false'
STATUS='dataimport?command=status'
urlCmd='http://${hostName}:${portNum}${SOLRPATH}/dataimport?command=${SOLRCMD}"
statusCmd='http://${hostName}:${portNum}${SOLRPATH}/dataimport?command=${STATUS}"
myStdErrLog=/tmp/myProject/myProg.stderr.$(/bin/date +%Y%m%d.%H%M)
outputDir=. 

# Operations
wget -O $outputDir/check_status_update_index.txt ${statusCmd} 2> ${myStdErrLog}
status=$(fgrep idle $outputDir/check_status_update_index.txt) 
case "${status}" in 
    *idle* ) .... ;; 
    * ) echo "unknown status = ${status} or similar" 1>&2 ;; 
 esac
```

All I really understand is that we get urlcmd and statuscmd built up from the varialbes, but I dont understand what the operation does. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: i think it won't work due to missing value of `$SOLRCMD`, anyway, the purpose of this script is to perform data import - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First there are bugs in the lines

```
urlCmd='..."
statusCmd='..."
```

Since they end with double quotes and include variables, they need to start with double quotes as well.

Variable `urlCmd` is never used. Not a bug, but it isn't nice either.

`wget` retrieves the status via the `statusCmd` and `fgrep` tries to extract the status. This status is then evaluated in the case statement.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it looks like it tries to download data from a website and pipes status to myStdErrLog.